# Multiple android.intent.action.MAIN in manifest xml file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am new to Android development I seen lots of tutorial where they have only `android.intent.action.MAIN` which is basically a start activity of the application.

But, in the android app demos, I have seen multiple `android.intent.action.MAIN` statements in *mainfest.xml*.  Can anyone explain why the `mainfest.xml` has multiple `android.intent.action.MAIN` statements?

And, in which scenarios we are supposed to have multiple `MAIN`s in manifest.xml?

Answer (score 21):

They're different entry points into the program. For instance, I just created two activities, both of which had the typical intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

It turns out that my launcher screen now has two different icons for the same program, one for each different activity. This makes sense, since the MAIN/LAUNCHER intent filter essentially tells android that the activity is the app's starting activity. Nothing in android's intent filter model forces each app to have one and only one starting activity.

Comment: I think only the `MAIN` intent filter is the one that allows the activity as the app's starting activity. If you omit the `LAUNCHER` one, no icon will be created. At least this is what I observe on my test device.

Answer (score 0):

LAUNCHER is the category, while MAIN is the action.

MAIN defines an entry point, specifying a way the app can be launched. For example, Consider an App which has 3 activities,

1. SplashActivity

   ```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
   ```
2. EmailActivity

   ```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL" />
    </intent-filter>
   ```
3. PlayMusicActivity

   ```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC" />
    </intent-filter>
   ```

If I click on the app icon on the home screen i.e launcher, I see Splash Activity.

If I click on a email address from a Messaging app, the system will show me a list of apps that support sending mail including my app(basically it searches for a specific combination of the intent filter provided by all applications)  And when I select my app, EmailActivity will be launched.

If I open a file browser and click on an audio file, my app will be listed to open this file, and PlayMusicActivity will be opened.

So, **ACTION.MAIN** is the different 'enrty' points or the different 'ways' the app can be launched.

CATEGORY will tell what type of launch it can be.