# why "Open" button after installing apk on android device is disabled?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have two projects and I want to combine them together.When I install each of them separately on **device** ,"**Open**" button (in page that has been represented after successful installation) is enabled.But when I combine them,"Open" button will be disabled, although installation process will be completed successful.I guess that this error is because of **manifest** file,but I am not sure.Thanks you in regards your time.
[image]

Comment: there is no Activity with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in manifest file?

Comment: Are both of the projects apps?

Comment: Edir your question and post your manifest file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say for certain without seeing your manifest, but my guess is that when you combined the two projects, you ended up with two activities that each included:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`
</intent-filter>
```

If you make sure to only say that in the activity you want to open with the "Open" button, I imagine it will work.

**Edit:** To be clear, [it's fine to have multiple entry points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109621/1427098) like this, but it still seems likely to explain that "Open" button being disabled, since it's ambiguous what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after merging code and it turned out that there was an illegal value in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Removing the illegal value fixed the issue. 
So, make sure to validate your file for errors.