# Multiple android.intent.action.MAIN

Tags: android

In the android app demos, I have seen multiple `android.intent.action.MAIN` statements in  `mainfest.xml`. Every Activity declared in `manifest.xml` had `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE` but only one Activity had `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Can anyone explain why the `mainfest.xml` has multiple `android.intent.action.MAIN` statements?  In which scenarios we are supposed to have multiple MAINs in `manifest.xml`? And why `android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE` is needed?

Comment: What IDE are you using ? I assume you may have just checked on a checkbox that says "Make Default Activity" , when creating new activities.

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi i'm using Eclipse. AppDemos is sample code that get from original sdk bundle.

Comment: @NaiveBz Take a look at the answer in here :- [Multiple android.intent.action.MAIN in mainfest xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109572/multiple-android-intent-action-main-in-mainfest-xml-file/8109621)